# How to handle Google Maps callback using Ionic 3

Tags: angular, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, ionic3, angular5

All the Ionic 2|3 / Google Maps JavaScript API public Projects in GitHub Contains this same Bug.

I'm working with Ionic 3 and I'm trying to integrate Google Maps JavaScript API. I decided to integrate it manually because I need to use a custom configuration.

## index.html:

```
  <!-- GOOGLE MAP -->
  <script async defer
      src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?
      key=...
      &libraries=places
      &callback=initialize">
  </script>

  <!-- cordova.js required for cordova apps (remove if not needed) -->
  <script src="cordova.js"></script>
```

The problem is that I don't know how to handle the **callback** which is offered by the API mentioned at the end of the script URL.

If I delete the callback from the URL, the map becomes unstable. Sometimes it works and sometimes I have the famous error "google is not defined". This is because the **initMap()** in my **home.ts** and the loading of the Google Map API are not synchronized. So, if the Google Maps API is loaded before the App calls **initMap()** it works correctly and vice versa.

So please how can I handle this callback with Angular 5 to take off this instability?

Comment: Remember to always delete your Google Maps API key from the URL

Comment: @RicardoFaria: Thank you

Comment: I'm facing a similar issue. I looked into this npm package to hook into the event when the api was loaded: https://www.npmjs.com/package/google-maps-api-loader but I couldn't get it working for me. I ended up using the Angular Google Maps package purely to load the api, injecting the mapsAPILoader into my component, and then using mapsAPILoader.then() and putting any references to the google object inside the callback. This is working for me, but it feels like a hack. Let me know if you figure out a better solution.

Comment: @BrendanWhiting :  I found a dirty solution also, just add @IonicPage() to your Component, I do not know how it works but it becomes stable anyway, have you any idea how it works with @IonicPage() ???

Comment: @BrendanWhiting: Would you post your solution anyway please

Comment: First of all, I should mention we could avoid all of this by putting the script tag before the body tag and taking away ‘async defer’. Then it will load the google maps javascript before it does anything else, but this will slow down the loading of your app.

My solution is to use the angular google maps package. In app.module.ts you put:
```
import { AgmCoreModule } from '@agm/core';
```

and then in the imports array:
```
AgmCoreModule.forRoot({
      apiKey: 'YOUR_GOOGLE_MAPS_API_KEY'
    })
```

Comment: Then I have a service where I need access to the google maps api:

Comment: @Injectable()
export class AutocompleteProvider {
  googleAutocompleteService;

  constructor(private mapsAPILoader: MapsAPILoader) {
    this.mapsAPILoader.load().then(() => {
      this.googleAutocompleteService = new google.maps.places.AutocompleteService();
    })
  }

  getPlacePredictions(input) {
    if (input) {
      return new Promise(resolve => {
        this.mapsAPILoader.load().then(() => {
          this.googleAutocompleteService.getPlacePredictions({input}, results => {
            resolve(results);
          });
        })
      });
    } 
  }
}

Comment: sorry it's not formatting code properly in the comment

Comment: Thank you anyway @BrendanWhiting, and for IonicPage() have you any idea why it becomes stable when I use it in my component ?

Comment: Not sure. Are your pages lazy loaded?